# Organic Groups Views Contextual Filters

Tags: organic-groups, views

We have a country based site that needs to have an unfiltered view of various content types and a filtered view per country. We have implemented the countries with Organic groups but can't seem to get the contextual filters to limit the view based on the OG name in the URL. Is there anyone that has done something like this with OG?

Answer (score 6):

Under **Relationships**, I choose "OG membership: OG membership from Node".

Then under **Contextual Filters**, I choose "OG membership: Group ID".

The last step is to select the Provide default value and choose "Type: Current OG group from context" under the **WHEN THE FILTER VALUE IS NOT IN THE URL** heading. Attached is a picture of what I mean.

[Contextual Filter setup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h7g5N.png)

Answer (score 0):

This link helped me:
http://drupaleasy.com/blogs/ultimike/2013/05/sneaky-previously-undocumented-views-feature

It says it's for overriding the title, but should still work for your scenario.